# Laravel parent class property inheritance problem

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

In laravel, I have a child class (code shortened for clarity):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller {
    ...
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $twilio = new Client($this->sid, $this->authToken);

        $user = $twilio->chat->v2->services(env("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID"))
                ->users
                ->create($data['username']);

    }
    ...
}
```

And I have the parent class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public $sid;
    public $authToken;
    public $serviceId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        $this->authToken = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN", true);
        $this->serviceId = getenv("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID");

    }
}
```

Still, I get this error:

```
"message": "Argument 1 passed to Twilio\\Rest\\Chat\\V2\\ServiceList::getContext() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/fingxtbh/thisnthat.com/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Chat/V2.php on line 80",
"exception": "TypeError",
"file": "/home/fingxtbh/thisnthat.com/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Chat/V2/ServiceList.php",
"line": 131,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/home/fingxtbh/thisnthat.com/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Chat/V2.php",
        "line": 80,
        "function": "getContext",
        "class": "Twilio\\Rest\\Chat\\V2\\ServiceList",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/fingxtbh/thisnthat.com/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php",
        "line": 104,
```

The
Why isn't the variable $this->serviceId being read correctly from the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the env call should be like this?

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->sid = env("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    $this->authToken = env("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN", true);
    $this->serviceId = env("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID");

}
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: if you change your construct to dd(env("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID")); does it shows the correct enviromment data? maybe you have misspelled it...

Comment: If I put that I get:

<script>
 Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact, .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse, .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; }'; (doc.documentEl
.....

Comment: you are not seeing it on the browser? if you are using console try with an echo --> echo env("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID");

Comment: No. I use postman. This method is consumed by the client, which is another app.

Comment: The thing is, if I put
$user = $twilio->chat->v2->services(env("TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID"))
                    ->users
                    ->create($data['username']);

in the RegisterController, then it works.

Comment: maybe you are missing the parent::__construct(); directive to call BaseController construct first

Comment: calling the parent::__construct(); did the trick. You can post this as an answer and I will accept it. If not, I will just post it myself.

Comment: glad to hear... also you are commenting inside an answer lol :), but i fixed my code to add the parent construct call